# Checking if the output is OK

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

I am running a command from the CMD via a batch file like so..

```
echo Step 3. Check TNSPING
tnsping vtdbs 2>NUL
    if not errorlevel 1 set error=PASSED
    if errorlevel 1 set error=FAILED
echo Result: %error%
```

But this only tells me if it actually was able to run the command..  When this command is ran it will give an output like so..

```
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah
blah blah
blah blah
blah blah
blah blah
OK (80 msec)
```

So line 8 should say "OK"   and as long as it does then.. `echo RESULT: Passed`  else `echo RESULT: Failed`

But not sure how to check and see if 8th line is .."OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more efficient solution, also tolerant if the output of `tnsping vtdbs` is <> 8 lines.

```
echo Step 3. Check TNSPING
set "error=FAILED"
for /f %%I in ('tnsping vtdbs 2^>NUL') do (
    if "%%I"=="OK" (set "error=PASSED" & goto next)
)
:next
echo Result: %error%
```

The reason you don't have to check if `%%I` matches `OK (??ms)` is that `for /f` defaults to `"tokens=1"` -- or, in other words, assigning `%%I` to the first word of each line.

Comment: My code is efficient from Line 8 to the end! Before line 8 might be an invalid `OK`!!

Comment: @mfm4aa - [Example output](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/network.112/e10836/connect.htm#BABJAGAG) of tnsping.  It's acceptable to assume that any line beginning with OK should signify success.

Comment: thanks i know both answers will work , but i like this one more Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "result="
for /f %%i in ('tnsping vtdbs 2^>NUL^|more +7') do if not defined result set "result=%%i"
if "%result%" equ "OK" (set "error=PASSED") else set "error=FAILED"
echo Result: %error%
endlocal
```