# Test multiple Oracle strings using a batch file and logging errors

Tags: oracle, batch-file, tns

I have over **900** Oracle strings in the following format:

```
sqlplus (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=c)(PORT=a))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=b)))
```

Can I create a batch file to test all 900 together using DOS? I do not want to test each manually. Getting the version will be helpful too. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you install cygwin? Should you use the cmmand prompt only?

Comment: By "DOS" you are actually talking about the Windows command prompt `cmd`, I guess...

Comment: There is no current Oracle client that runs on DOS. They all require at least Windows to run. So, no you can't do that in DOS - but you _can_ do it in the Windows command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file line by line ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527877/batch-script-read-line-by-line)) and use it as a argument like this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (alias.txt) do call :processline %%a

:processline
tnsping %*
goto :eof

:eof
```

You might need to use the trick from [Checking if the output is OK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546190/checking-if-the-output-is-ok) to check if connection is ok or not.

I would prefer [tnsping](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG378) over sqlplus, so you do not have to worry about username, password and actual command to execute.